# Tree command in C: exact output

Tags: c

I'll go straight to the point and I know this is a question already asked like here:

[Print a tree of file and subdirectories using only ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326504/print-a-tree-of-file-and-subdirectories-using-only-ascii-characters)

OR

[printing line like tree command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814788/printing-line-like-tree-command?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But my question is actually on the exact output of the command: "LC_ALL=C tree -n --charset=ascii [options] [dirs]"

My program looks like this and please excuse me for the messy code I write:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fnmatch.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//Functions prototypes
void printaTree(int, char *, int *, int *, int);
void printTreeconPattern(int livello, char * pattern);

//MAIN
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int checkgetopt;
    char * pattern;
    char * optargvalue;
    int maxHeight;
    int checkHidden = 0;
    int indice;
    int dirsindex = 0;
    char ** directories;
    directories = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));
    for (indice = optind; indice < argc; indice++) {
        directories[dirsindex] = malloc(strlen(argv[indice]) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(directories[dirsindex], argv[indice]);
        dirsindex++;
    }
    int livello = 0;
    int i;
    int countfiles = 0;
    int countDirs = 0;
    if (dirsindex == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", ".");
        printaTree(livello, ".", &countfiles, &countDirs, checkHidden);
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < dirsindex; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", directories[i]);
            printaTree(livello, directories[i], &countfiles, &countDirs, checkHidden);
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d directories, %d files\n", countDirs, countfiles);
    free(directories);
    return 0;
}

void printaTree(int livello, char * directory, int * filenum, int * dirnum, int hidden)
{
    struct dirent ** dobjects;
    int numeroOggetti = scandir(directory, &dobjects, NULL, alphasort);
    if (numeroOggetti == -1) {
        perror("scandir");
    }
    char pathnuovo[1024];
    int i;
    int checkSym = 0;
    char * buf;
    for (i = 0; i < numeroOggetti; i++) {
        if ((strcmp(dobjects[i]->d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(dobjects[i]->d_name, "..") == 0))
            continue;
        if (hidden == 0) {
            if (dobjects[i]->d_name[0] == '.') {
                continue;
            }
        }

        //Print how Tree command would print:
        if (i != numeroOggetti - 1) {
            if (livello != 0) {
                printf("%*s", livello * 4 - 1, "");
            } else {
                printf("%*s", livello, "");
            }
            printf("|-- ");
            printf("%s\n", dobjects[i]->d_name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (livello != 0) {
            printf("%*s", livello * 4 - 1, "");
        } else {
            printf("%*s", livello, "");
        }
        printf("`-- ");
        printf("%s\n", dobjects[i]->d_name);
    }
    if (dobjects[i]->d_type == DT_REG) {
        (*filenum)++;
    }
    if (dobjects[i]->d_type == DT_DIR) {
        (*dirnum)++;
        livello = livello + 1;
        snprintf(pathnuovo, sizeof pathnuovo, "%s%s%s", directory, "/", dobjects[i]->d_name);
        printaTree(livello, pathnuovo, filenum, dirnum, hidden);
        livello = livello - 1;
    }
}
```

So my code actually works, I have left out parts where my code handles options on input and the Symbolic Link check in the dir entries.

On a test folder structured like this:

```
RootDIRname
file1
file2
dir1
    file4
    dir2
         file6
         file7
    dir3
        file10
        file11
file8
file9
```

My code outputs:

```
RootDIRname
|-- file1
|-- file2
|-- dir1
    |-- file4
    |-- dir2
        |-- file6
        `-- file7
    `-- dir3
        |-- file10
        `-- file11
|-- file8
`-- file9
```

The exact output should be instead:

```
RootDIRname
|-- file1
|-- file2
|-- dir1
|   |-- file4
|   |-- dir2
|   |   |-- file6
|   |   `-- file7
|   `-- dir3
|       |-- file10
|       `-- file11
|-- file8
`-- file9
```

I tried many ways on formatting but still I'm missing something, if I do a loop I achieve a similar output to the correct one, but there would be extra pipes "|" for each level even when I shouldn't have them (i.e. "dir3" entries).

I hope someone could lend me an hand.
Thank you in advance!
If there's need of editing code or providing more infos please tell me.

EDIT: So my idea on this is that I need to print pipes only if there are still directory entries in previous levels. But this would mean that I would have to keep track of these levels through the recursive call.
How can I do that?
I could do a copy of my Dirent structure already filled, but then I don't think it will print pipes on the very first level when the actual level is 3, for example.

I really don't need code as much as I need proper ideas in order to get it working correctly :/

Comment: Try to describe generically but precisely where your pipe-characters are missing. That should put you on track for finding the algorithm.

Comment: I edited the body of my question inserting one of my ideas in order to get it to work. Is there any way to do that without storing previous levels?

Comment: You need another parameter to the recursive call that contains an array of the previous indentations. This will tell you were to put pipes.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this method out.

Comment: Ok I was trying to do that, but I am a little confused on what I need. Do I need a multi-dimensional array which I can store levels on rows and dir entries on columns?
I'm sorry but I probably need more precise perspectives on this matter, how would you guys do that?

Comment: @Luca9504 did you manage to solve your problem? If so, can you share your solution?